# How to make table TR row border top and bottom, without push previous and late rows to move?

Tags: css

I have a table. I want that when user mouse up a row, the selected row is having this:

```
.list-orders tr:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;
}
```

However, when those borders are getting applied, the whole table and its rows is like getting blink up and down.

I want to achieve something like Gmail hover effect.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can always add the same borders in non-hover state with transparent color. Something like: `border-top: 1px solid transparent;` and `border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same as Gmail you can use `box-shadow` instead of applying borders to the `tr` element.

```css
.list-orders tr:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000000;
}
```

```html
<table class="list-orders">
    <tr>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>a3</td>
        <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Box Shadow

Easier to use [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow):

```
tr:hover
{
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 #dadce0, inset -1px 0 0 #dadce0, 
  0 1px 2px 0 rgba(60,64,67,.3), 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(60,64,67,.15); */
}
```

Helper: https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

```css
tr td{
 cursor: pointer;
}
tr:hover
{
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 #dadce0, inset -1px 0 0 #dadce0, 
  0 1px 2px 0 rgba(60,64,67,.3), 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(60,64,67,.15); */
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Borders

By borders - less flexible (Buggy when you set diff bottom/top borders). 
Set before (Transparent + width) & Hover (change color + width)

```
tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

tr:hover td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr td{
 cursor: pointer;
}
tr {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

tr:hover td {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```